# Using compound XPath Predicates to search XML message

Tags: xml, xpath, predicate

I'm having trouble figuring out how to select data using a compound XPath query so that I can essentially find the 5th column of row in my data.  Here is my example XML:

```
<sample>
 <OBX>
   <field position="1">1</field>
   <field position="2">My Value</field>
 </OBX>
 <OBX>
   <field position="1">2</field>
   <field position="2">My other (and more important) value</field>
 </OBX>
</sample>
```

Basically all I need to do is find the value of [field @position='2'] when [field @position='1'] is equal to 2.  I am trying:

```
OBX[./field[@position='1']='2']/field[@position='2']
```

but this doesn't come up with any value.  What would be the proper way to get this accomplished?

Thanks,

Mike

Comment: Good question, +1. See my answer for a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**I have verified that this XPath expression**:

```
/*/OBX[field[@position='1']='2']/field[@position='2']
```

**when evaluated against the provided XML document:**

```
<sample>
 <OBX>
   <field position="1">1</field>
   <field position="2">My Value</field>
 </OBX>
 <OBX>
   <field position="1">2</field>
   <field position="2">My other (and more important) value</field>
 </OBX>
</sample>
```

**does select the required node**

**Here is a demonstration, using XSLT as the XPath hosting language:**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

 <xsl:template match="/">
  <xsl:copy-of select="/*/OBX[field[@position='1']='2']/field[@position='2']"/>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when this transformation is applied against the provided XML document, the correct result is produced**:

```
<field position="2">My other (and more important) value</field>
```